# pub: Running a script from dependency with colon syntax fails

Tags: dart

I am reading [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-run#running-a-script-in-a-dependency) of the Dart's pub `run` command and it specifies the following syntax with a colon after the package name to run the script from the dependency package:

> pub run foo:bar arg

But I remember (and double-checked it) that for code generation with `build_runner` I always did this, without a colon:

> flutter pub run build_runner build

Moreover, if I try to run the `build_runner build` with a colon syntax like

> flutter pub run build_runner: build

then it gives me an error: `Could not find bin/.dart in package build_runner.`

Why is that?